# Calculate group with highest defective rate

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, small-sample, fishers-exact-test

I have data on several types of machines, each with a different rate of failure. I have samples of failures/non-failures for each machine type. The samples are small relative to the population range from 10 to 200 for populations of ~ several million.

I'd like to identify if the machine type with the highest failure rate has a statistically significant higher rate of failures than the others. I've read using Fisher's exact test can show whether two proportions are DIFFERENT, but how would I demonstrate which machine has the HIGHEST failure rate?

Edit:  I also read about the marascuilo procedure which looks like it may be what I’m looking for: itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc474.htm

Comment: Surely the machine with the highest failure rate is the machine with the highest fraction of failures. Do you have a different statistical question in mind? Are you looking for some sort of test that one of the machines has a significantly higher failure rate? (Not all questions require a statistical test beyond a ranking of the observed rates.)

Comment: Yes, exactly what I’m looking for, If I can show that the highest failure rate has a statistically significant higher failure rate than the others. I also read about the marascuilo procedure which looks like it may be what I’m looking for: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc474.htm